# find the occurrence of every character and word in ascending order -php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make an application which will take an input string and in return application finds the occurrence of every character in ascending order as well as the occurrence of words also in ascending order.

I am confused why its showing 18 times in letter count  and how to sort it .

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="counter.php">

    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="string">
    </textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['string'])) {
    $string=$_POST['string'];

    echo("Counting Words").'<br>';
    print_r(array_count_values(str_word_count($string,1)));

    echo '<br>';

    echo("Letter Count").'<br>';

    $chart = count_chars($string, 1); 

    echo '<br>';

    foreach($chart as $letter=>$frequency)
    echo chr($letter)."  $frequency times<br />";

}
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Counting Words

```
Array ( [A] => 1 [string] => 1 [with] => 1 [certain] => 1 [words] => 2 [occuring] => 1 [more] => 1 [often] => 1 [than] => 1 [other] => 1 )
```

> Letter Count

```
18 times
A 1 times
a 2 times
c 3 times
d 2 times
e 4 times
f 1 times
g 2 times
h 3 times
i 4 times
m 1 times
n 5 times
o 6 times
r 7 times
s 3 times
t 6 times
u 1 times
w 3 times
```

Comment: 18 times you have a "space"? How to sort arrays is asked millions of times - use search here or on google.

Comment: There are [many sort functions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). Didn't you try them yet? What is the issue with them, if any?

Answer (score 0):

There is a **lot** of built-in php function, try to check them out first. One of them you can use is called substring count.(http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php).

```
<?php
$text = 'This is a test';
echo strlen($text); // 14

echo substr_count($text, 'is'); // 2

// the string is reduced to 's is a test', so it prints 1
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 3);

// the text is reduced to 's i', so it prints 0
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 3, 3);

// generates a warning because 5+10 > 14
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 5, 10);
```

You just need to check for each letter and occurance and repeating it in a set of array, to find each character occurence.